# How to pass closure connection object to Async method for Postgress Transaction rollback

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-diesel

In Postgres, I have many SQL transactions which are executed from different threads and need to rollback all the transactions if anyone fails

code is like this -

```
 dbconn.transaction::<_, DieselError, _>(  |conn| {

  tokio::spawn( insert_salary_table(conn) );
  tokio::spawn( insert_user_table(conn) );
  tokio::spawn( insert_user_table(conn) );

}
```

The problem here is, that I am not. able to borrow the conn object out of the transaction closure block

Any suggestion will be really helpful.

Note: without  tokio::spawn it is working, but my requirement as per the use case to use an async call.  I tried calling these async functions from runtime.block_on()  but facing the same error.

Comment: Why do you split transaction (operation intended to be **atomic**) into independent tasks?

Comment: lots of transactions are triggered dynamically

Comment: Ok. But then _each transaction_ should be each own task. Why would you want to split it further? You probably want to perform each transaction in order (firstly insert salary, then user, then user in your example). You don't have any guarantee that those task would runt in this order.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `async` stuff in a transaction with Diesel by using the [diesel-async](https://crates.io/crates/diesel-async) crate:

```rust
use scoped_futures::ScopedFutureExt;
use diesel_async::AsyncConnection;

dbconn.transaction::<(), DieselError, _>(|conn| async move {
    insert_salary_table(conn).await?;
    insert_user_table(conn).await?;
    insert_user_table(conn).await?;

    Ok(())
}.scope_boxed()).await;
```

Consult the documentation on [`transaction`](https://docs.rs/diesel-async/latest/diesel_async/trait.AsyncConnection.html#method.transaction) for more info. Since your functions are `async`, they should be using the diesel-async version of `RunQueryDsl` inside them anyway to avoid blocking your executor.

---

> ... transactions which are executed from different threads and need to rollback all the transactions if anyone fails

This will not enable your transaction to be multi-threaded, and cannot be. The `conn` provided is an exclusive reference and thus can't be used in two places simultaneously.